# Repackaged Android App drawing issues on Blackberry Playbook simulator

Tags: android, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-playbook

I am trying to repackage a small game I made for Android to be used on the Blackberry Playbook.

I was able to repackage it and deploy to the Blackberry Simulator on vmware just fine, except the redrawing on the simulator just behaves very strangely.  For example I get a lot of flickering when things redraw.  And sometimes half the screen draws and the other half doesn't. Sometimes the bottom portion of the screen disappears and all the images get shifted up.

This mostly seems to happen when I'm swapping button images, or using ImageView to do little animations and such.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Is it a simulator issue, or will it occur on the Playbook as well?  Any idea how to fix?

Comment: You're not alone. My app was flickering all over the place with buttons disappearing and stuff. Also tab and activity changes worked quite randomly and left ghost views on top of other views. Probably the simulator's fault. But we'll know for sure if my app bounces back from the verification phase. ;)

Comment: Oh, and also, switching between portrait and landscape lead to all kinds of irrecoverable drawing horrors.

Comment: Hopefully an emulator bug, otherwise we don't get our free PlayBooks :o

Comment: Ok, so at least other people are having the same issue... ugh... I hate the simulator, I hope it is a simulator issue!

Comment: My app flickers like crazy so I cannot test it beyond some very basic "yup the buttons are there" kind of way. I tried two builds of the 2.0 VM image and both suffered the exact same problem - mad repainting issues, flickering & unresponsiveness. I submitted my app anyway. If they send me a PlayBook I'll test it against the actual hardware.

Comment: My app with massive drawing issues in the simulator got approved ;-)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, I'm sending my in and see if it gets accepted.

Comment: Same problem here with my app, which is not a game but a very simple app with no animation. It is absolutely unusable on the simulator (awful flickering, even when idle and the app is still, previous frames flicker periodically). Not to mention the buggy handling of orientation changes.

Comment: Guys, I hope all your apps got approved despite those flickerings in the simulator and you can properly test them in your new shiny promotional PlayBooks... Can we close the question?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm I have experienced the same flickering problems on the Simulator, but I published my repackaged Android app on the BlackBerry AppWorld, got the promotional PlayBook, and the app works fine on the real device. It is definitely the Simulator problem.